# How to measure the mechanical vibration when a hammer hits a nail?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science, elasticity, vibrations

I want to know the exact location of the vibration sensor that can be placed to measure the vibrations created by a hammer hits the nail.

Comment: You place it where you would want to measure the vibrations... I'm not sure what this is actually asking about.

Comment: If you want the vibrations in the nail then on the nail, if the vibrations of the hammer after it has bounced off the nail then on the hammer, or if the vibrations in the bit of wood then on the wood... But nail and wood vibrations will be probably affected by the other object...

Answer (score 1):

Use a piezoelectric microphone for the sensor. place the sensor as close as possible to the nail you will strike. Affix a wire to the hammer and another to the nail and connect these wires to the trigger line of a fast a-to-d converter/data logger or a storage oscilloscope and adjust the trigger sense knob so that when the hammer face touches the nail head, data capture or the oscilloscope sweep is initiated.